# How to comment a vuetify code in a vue.js file

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have tried `//`,`/*----*/`,`{{-----}}`, but none of them are not seem to be work.

Comment: Check this Link. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228833/how-to-comment-code-in-a-vue-js-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228833/how-to-comment-code-in-a-vue-js-file)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use simple HTML comments in your vue code.

```
<!-- Your Vuetify code -->
```

Comment: but if you have something like white--text , it does not work?

Comment: @KickButtowski For the comment to work, the entire `<!--` and `-->` is required. So the `--` in `white--text` would not interfere with a comment or cause a comment to occur.

Comment: The HTML comments are *not* a universal solution. They only work if you comment out *entire components*! Say you're testing _props_ in a component and your beautifier lays them on separate lines. Now, comment out one of them with `<!-- -->`, build that and let me know how it went, because  Vue 2.6.12 / Vuetify 2.4.4 beg to differ.

If your solution is not universal, please constrain it. Trying before pouring out knowledge is also a useful tip that more SO users could follow.