# How do I make Vue stop rendering template comments?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue application (2.6.0) which I've just started commenting the template for. I'm using this sort of comment syntax:

```
        <--! This component maps communities and allows you to add new ones -->
```

Unfortunately, it is showing up inside my components when rendered. How do I make this stop?

Comment: Can you please provide more context to it? 

Can you paste the full code of the component. 

Those comments should work, if they are in `<template>` section, but if they are in `script` section, you should be using `//` and `/**/`.

Comment: These comments are in the <template> section. 

The component is quite large, I'd rather not paste the whole thing.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228833/how-to-comment-code-in-a-vue-js-file

Comment: That's odd, comments are not rendered by default unless you specified [`comments: true`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#comments). Is it a single file component built with webpack?

Comment: It is built with Vue CLI, and I'm running the dev version with npm run serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error:

```
<--! This component maps communities and allows you to add new ones -->
^^^^
```

It should be

```
<!--
```